# UIBarButtonItem clicked side menu not open

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I am developing iOS App.Add `UIBarButtonItem` on Custom `UIView`.Button Added Successfully.But, when I click on button enter on selector action.But Side menu not open.
Please Help thanks in Advance.

Here is the Code:

```
- (void)sideButton{
    UIImage *menuButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menu-icon.png"];// set your image Name here
    UIButton *btnToggle = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnToggle setImage:menuButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnToggle addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btnToggle.frame = CGRectMake(10, 30, 25, 25);
    [_sideView addSubview:btnToggle]; //sideView is UIView

    _menuBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnToggle];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = _menuBarButton;
}
- (IBAction)checkButtonTapped:(id)sender{
    SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = self.revealViewController;
    if ( revealViewController ){
        [_menuBarButton setTarget: self.revealViewController];
        [_menuBarButton setAction: @selector( revealToggle: )];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the code of `checkButtonTapped`

Comment: requestButton ????

Comment: there is no need to add to `_slideView` and by default navigation leftbarbutton item is displayed, so remove this line ` [_sideView addSubview:btnToggle];` and try

Answer (score 0):

You need to add method for checkButtonTapped.

```
-(void) checkButtonTapped:(UIButton*)sender {
//write your button action here.
}
```

If you want to use existing method you must mention it into the **addTarget** method.

Comment: change - (IBAction)checkButtonTapped:(id)sender using -(void) checkButtonTapped:(UIButton*)sender

Comment: side menu not open when i click side button

Comment: Does button click works? that is you debug points hits when you click button?

Comment: yes button clicked.to enter selector method.but side menu not open

Comment: @Deepak: you wanted a solution that your selector does not work. And i have given you solution.I think i should be thanked if you accept my answer.
And you said your side menu is not opening. That's another issue. You can make another question for this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this

```
UIButton *btnToggle = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

Into this

```
UIButton *btnToggle = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,50,50)];
```

Tell me if this works

Comment: its not Working

Comment: Write an NSLog in the `checkButtonTapped` action and see if it prints